# Webservice without public WSDL is an anti pattern?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, corba

I had an endless argument with a friend recently. **Our company exposes web services endpoints without their WSDL**. WSDLs are hidden inside the system.

Some colleague say "it's better for the security". I say WHAAAAT ?
Another argument is "You don't need to expose the WSDL, because it is only used at development time".

So basically they say that when someone consume our web service, there is always a time where you pass the WSDL by email, in order to let them build a client. Once you are in prod, the WSDL is no longer used.

So, please, tell me I'm right. Tell me that when you expose a service to the outside world, you MUST expose the contract with the endpoint. It's THE RULE. talking about development is irrelevant here, right ?

My friend says that I'm biased because I wrote a dynamic gateway, so I need the WSDL at runtime, and this kind of scenario is very rare.

What really pisses me off in all of this is that **the WSDL is considered as the .lib and .h of a .DLL or .SO**, it's "just a thing required at development time".

I don't know what it is for CORBA and IDL... Does the IDL was exposed to the public at runtime ?

So, what is the right thing here ? I'm lost. The client is intended to receive the WSDL at runtime right ? Or not ? It should perform some kind of validation at runtime right ?

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong. Making a good interface can take a lot of effort, years of experience, and the WSDL is a very detailed description of the service. If that is a secret, so be it. As authentication might be included, there is also a potential security issue.

I would like to argue that you should NEVER download the WSDL from a service if you can get the original instead. The online WSDLs are sometimes generated by the SOAP framework and things documentation will often not be included. Furthermore the endpoint address should always be explicitly set, never use the value which might be included in the WSDL.

In fact the right way to communicate the service definiton is not only a well-defined set of WSDL / XSDs but also with concrete request/response examples in including error responses.

Relying on downloading a WSDL to bootstrap your service is a receipt for disaster (if this stops your app from starting).

Comment: ok but "receipt for disaster" ? really ? I prefer to know that the service is not there when I check the WSDL instead of crashing when I call a method on a dead endpoint. This case, precisely, is a disaster.

Comment: What you want is a health-check. 

Returning a 503 is not a disaster. No response at an URL is a disaster.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use a webservice method for a health-check, because a method DO something. The whole purpose of the WSDL is to present the service contract and to know it is healthy and running.
If the endpoints are wrong in the WSDL, It is absolutely not normal.

Comment: If you want to avoid calling on a dead endpoint, you need a continous health check which runs repeatedly. A simple check on startup is not sufficient.

Comment: If I follow you correctly, there is no value to expose the WSDL, so basically it is like the IDL in CORBA or COM. The value of the WSDL is to be "language-neutral" (I can produce a C# client, or a Java client with it.). That's all.

Comment: Yes, it is an accurate technical description of the service, for use in both clients and servers.

Comment: it would be great to ear an opposite advice... if not, I will gracefully accept my defeat :-)

Comment: I read again your response, and I didn't notice that in fact you are talking about top-down approach here: write a nice WSDL contract then generate java. In my company we do the inverse. We have no big constraints on the contract because it is between our own services. So I'm not sure anymore your arguments are ok in bottom-up approach, because the WSDL exposed by the server is the only one that exists in the system.